# DynamoDB - Reducing number of queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

After my users log in the app makes too many requests to DynamoDB and I am thinking about different ways to reduce the number of calls.

The app allows user to trigger certain alerts that get sent to other users. For instance: "Shipment received, come to the deck", "Shipment completed", etc.

These are the calls made:

1. Get company's software license expiration date.
2. Get the computer's location in the building (i.e. "Office A").
3. Get the kinds of alerts that can be triggered (i.e. "Shipment received, come to the deck", "Shipment completed", etc).
4. Get information about the user (i.e. company teams the user belongs to, and admin level the user has (which can be 0, 1, 2, or 3).

Potential solutions I have though about:

1. Put the company's license expiration date as an attribute of each computer (This would reduce the number of queries by 1). However, if I need to update the company's license expiration date, then I need to update it for EVERY SINGLE computer I have in the system, which sounds impractical to me since I may have 200, 300 or perhaps even more computers in the database.
2. Add the company's license expiration date as an attribute of the alerts (This would reduce the number of queries by 1); which seems more reasonable because there are only about 15 different kinds of alerts, so if I need to change the license expiration date later on, it is not too bad.
3. Cache information on the user's device; however, I can't seem to find a good strategy to keep the information stored locally as updated as possible.

I still think these 3 options do not sound too good, so I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Is there a good way to reduce the number of calls? I am retrieving information about 4 different entities (license, computer, alert, user), should I leave those 4 calls after users log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are few things that can be done wrt each component.

1. Get information about the user

   keep it in session store and whenever details changes update the store. session stores are usually implemented using cache like redis.
2. Computer location

   Keep it in a distributed cache like redis. lazily initialise it. and whenever new write happens to computer location (rare IMO) remove the entry from redis using dynamodb streams and aws lambda.
3. Kind of alerts

   Same as Computer location
4. License expiration date

   If possible don't allow license expiry date (issue a new one for these cases, so that traceability is maintained.) and cache licence expiry forever. OR same as Computer location.